# After inputting a value in QLineEdit(), I want to display only the rows in QTableWidget by pressing the search button

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

When you entered a value in the edit window created by the QLineEdit() function, and then clicked QPushButton, you tried to print only the rows that matched the values ​​entered in the edit window. If you press the search button without entering anything, you want to see all the results (rows) again.

I used setRowHidden() to do this, but I do not see the above results.

Is there a function that provides the above functions? I would like to know if there is a solution.

I tried changing the argument value of setRowHidden() to True or False, but I could not get the desired result.

```
def OnFilter(self):
    for i in range(0, tableWidget.rowCount()):
        item = tableWidget.item(i, 1)
        if (item is not None and item.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole) == (self.SearchEdit.text())):
            tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, False)
        else:
            tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, True)


self.SearchEdit = QLineEdit()
self.SearchButton = QPushButton("search")
self.SearchButton.clicked.connect(self.OnFilter)
```

If you press the search button after entering the value in the current edit window, only the corresponding line is output. However, if you try to view the entire value (row) by clearing the value entered in the edit window and pressing the search button, nothing will be output.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better, for example when you say: *Is there a function that provides the above functions?* what do you mean ?. It also provides a [mre]

Comment: sorry. next time, I will elaborate further and ask questions.
Thank you for your interest in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that when *self.SearchEdit.text() == ""*  all rows should be shown, but your code treats an empty string ("") same as a keyword and tries to match it in your table.

Put an if statement in your function so that if  *self.SearchEdit.text() == ""*, all rows are displayed.

You can do like this:

```
    def OnFilter(self):
        if self.SearchEdit.text() == "":
            for i in range(0, tableWidget.rowCount()):
                tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, False)
            return
        for i in range(0, tableWidget.rowCount()):
            item = tableWidget.item(i, 1)
            if (item is not None and item.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole) == 
            (self.SearchEdit.text())):
                tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, False)
            else:
                tableWidget.setRowHidden(i, True)
```